# Rspec error: invalid option --warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am working my way through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and have come to [section 3.2.1](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-TDD), where he first introduces test driven development and the use of Rspec. I believe I am faithfully following the tutorial (including editing the spec_helper.rb and static_pages_spec.rb files as directed).  I get to the point where I am directed to run:

```
$ bundle exec spec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

And I get the following message in response:

> invalid option --warnings
>
> please use --help for a listing of valid options

Admittedly, I am pretty new to all of this, but I have not been able to find an answer as to what this particular error message means (and what I am supposed to do).

My Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end


gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty old version of rspec. I'd suggest getting something newer (or you could edit your .rspec file to remove --warnings).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using that version (and the versions of the other gems listed in the gem file) so as to follow along with the tutorial.  I tried deleting --warnings from the .rspec file, and got an extensive error (too big for comment space here) beginning with: sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Capybara (NameError)

Comment: I ended up skipping ahead to http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-advanced_setup which, once set up, resolved my issues I was having earlier with the tutorial.  I think my second problem, as noted in comment above, was the way I originally worded the spec_helper.rb file

Answer (score 1):

I am also doing Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and had the exact same problem. Neither editing the .rspec file nor doing the advanced setup solved the problem. I eventually realized that the specs would run properly if I added "--options PATH" to the command:

> bundle exec rspec --options PATH spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

Comment: I'm wondering if you (or the op) tried closing all your terminal windows after editing your .rspec file to remove `--warnings`?  According to the rspec docs: `RSpec reads command line configuration options from files in two different
locations:

Local: "./.rspec" (i.e. in the project's root directory) Global: "~/.rspec" (i.e. in the user's home directory)

Options declared in the local file override those in the global file, while
those declared in RSpec.configure will override any ".rspec" file.`

Comment: The error message states that you cannot use the rspec command with a --warnings flag, so if you: 1) Don't explicitly call rspec with that flag, and 2) That flag isn't in the `your_project/.rspec` file, nor in `~/.rspec`, nor in `RSpec.configure` somewhere, e.g. spec_helper.rb, you shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: Turns out the .rspec file in my home directory had a `--warnings` flag, so I deleted it and now all the tests run perfectly! (I no longer need to write `--options PATH`)

Comment: I didn't realize that I had a .rspec file in my home directory at all so I was only looking at the one in my local directory, which never had a `--warnings"`flag to begin with. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.  You shouldn't have to close your terminal windows after editing .rspec.  Your welcome.